# android Lrucache: unable to retrieve cached bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, android-lru-cache

I am able to insert bitmap into `LruCache` but fails to retrieve previous decoded image. i am having more than 100 images in my db. when i am deoding it my gc mmemory is increasing.so i am implementing this to reuse the decoded image.

```
protected void onCreate()
{
    LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;
    codeforLru_oncreate();
    aa1=getBitmapFromMemCache(String.valueOf(aa));
    if (aa1 != null) 
    {
      iv.setImageBitmap(aa1);
    } 
    else
    {
      aa1= decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(aa);
      addBitmapToMemoryCache(String.valueOf(aa), aa1);
      iv.setImageBitmap(aa1);
    }
}
```

Getting max available VM memory, exceeding this amount will throw an OutOfMemory  exception. Stored in kilobytes as LruCache takes an `int` in its constructor.

```
public void codeforLru_oncreate() {

    final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
    // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
    final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 64;
    mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
        @Override
        protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
            // The cache size will be measured in kilobytes rather than
            // number of items.
            //app.setFlagForMemoryAlloc(1);
            return bitmap.getByteCount() / 1024;
        }
    };

}
   // code for adding bitmap into cache memory
  public void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) 
    {
    if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {

        mMemoryCache.put(key, bitmap);
    }
}



//code for get bitmap from cache memory
public Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
    return mMemoryCache.get(key);
}

//decoding here......
public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(byte[] decodethis)
{
     return                BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodethis,0,decodethis.length,option);
}
```

Comment: how do you know its not returning the decoded image?

Comment: Any reason you are using 1/64 max memory?

Comment: Check complete example of [LruCache and DiskLruCache](https://github.com/lalit3686/ImageCacheDemo)

Comment: @kenWolf: as i have increse my heap using android:largeheap="true" in manifest file.it now becomes 256 mb.Thus 256/64= 4 mb of lrucache.

Comment: @Amulya Khare: in oncreate, i am checking with toast it never get entered in if (aa1 != null) 
    {
      iv.setImageBitmap(aa1);
    }

Comment: This is because in `onCreate()` you just created the cache. So it will have nothing inside as yet.. if you put something inside and try to get it again.. if should work.. i see no problems..

Comment: I have called codeforLru_oncreate(); method in oncreate